# Javascript Slide show

Tags: javascript

I have a simple fading slide-show which works great for a while, but runs to about 300 images. After a while it starts jumping and missing some, which I assume is down to too many images being loaded. Is there a way of 'unloading' images once viewed, or is it likely to be something else?

Comment: It is likely to be something else.

Comment: show it to us so we could help

Answer (score -1):

Let all images load before you display the slide show, or skip not loaded images.

You could do this like this for example:

```
var images = ['./path1.jpg', './path2.jpg']; // Array with all images
var imageCount, imagesLoaded, c;

imageCount = images.length; // Get images count
imagesLoaded = 0;

for (c = 0; c < imageCount ; c++){ // Loop thorough all images
  var image = document.createElement('img'); // Create img tag
  image.setAttribute('src', images[c]); // Set src attribute
  document.body.appendChild(image); // Add img tag to body

  image.onload = function() { 
    imagesLoaded++; // Add loaded image to loaded images count

    console.log('Loaded: ' + imagesLoaded + '/' + imageCount); // debug

    if (imagesLoaded == imageCount){ // when all images loaded   
      // Start your slideshow
    }
  }
}
```